# Side Panel using only CSS

Tags: css, jsp

I'm working on JSP currently. I'm trying to create a side panel menu along with a header. How can I design it using only css and not JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not create side panels with JQuery.  JQuery is, basically, JavaScript.

To create side panels I would recommend [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com)

[image: Nav list example]

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
   <li class="nav-header">List header</li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
</ul>
```